# PHP basic regular expression

Tags: php, regex

For example i've this kind of content

```
<div id="t1" class="tt" tag='t2"><div class="t3">tee</div><a href='#'>test</a><span>test</span><div>asdf</div></div>

<div id="t1" class="tt" tag='t2"><div class="t3">tee</div><a href='#'>test</a><span>test</span><div>asdf</div></div>
```

I am trying to use preg_match to get the content between parent div, so here the parent divs means `<div id="t1"`. I do i use preg_match or is there any other way to get the data between those divs?

Comment: [PONIES!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/57191)

Comment: Did you try something? Just adding "advance" to a question title does not entitle you to effortful answers without own research.

Answer (score 5):

A regular expression is the wrong tool for this job.  You want a DOM parser.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$t1 = $dom->getElementById('t1');
echo $t1->nodeValue;
```

This will only return you the text, if you want the `innerHTML`, try this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$t1 = $dom->getElementById('t1');

$innerHTML = '';
foreach($t1->childNodes as $child){
    $innerHTML .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
echo $innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't attempt to parse HTML with regex: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/146406)

Use a PHP DOM library like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/